# Can't put data in json file

Tags: android, json

I can not change the existing parameter in the json file. Moreover, it is read through getString, everything is fine, but it is not written
I am trying to write it like this:

```
            JSONObject json=new JSONObject(JsonDataFromAsset("tests.json"));
            JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("abouttests");
            JSONObject userData=jsonArray.getJSONObject(position);
            userData.put("bestresult",rightanswercount);
             //rightanswercount its int
            }
          catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
             }
 
 private String JsonDataFromAsset(String fileName) {
        String json = null;
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open(fileName);
            int sizeOfFile = inputStream.available();
            byte[] bufferData = new byte[sizeOfFile];
            inputStream.read(bufferData);
            inputStream.close();
            json = new String(bufferData, "UTF-8");
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;
    }
```

Json file has structure:

```
  "abouttests": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Тест 1:Знание первой темы",
      "description": "Это тест первый:)",
      "bestresult": 2,
      "questioncount": 3
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Тест 2:Знание второй темы",
      "description": "Это тест второй:)",
      "bestresult": 0,
      "questioncount": 3
    }
  ]}
```

Comment: Does `e.printStackTrace();` print anything?

Comment: @HB,There are no errors, but maybe I'm looking in the wrong place? Where can I see it? What error tag should be?